# Ajax calendar extender issue on ajax modal popup?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I added ajax calendar extender on ajax modal popup in asp.net web form but it doesn't show month and year.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtdateCalendar" runat="server" Width="220px" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgPopup" runat="server" ImageUrl="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/calendar-alt-512.png" Height="20px" Width="30px"  /> 
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarBirth" TargetControlID ="txtdateCalendar" CssClass="cal_Theme1" PopupButtonID="imgPopup" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
```

[image: Month is not showing exactly]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Most probably this is css related issue as month names are cut off and not showing up properly. You can inspect the month names row using browser developer tool and try adjusting margin or padding

Comment: I did inspect but its showing style { top:139 } and its not change as well, is it possible to add style into the calendar extender tag?

Comment: @KiranGirase You can specify [CssClass](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki/CalendarExtender#properties) property to apply your custom style.

Comment: The 139 or -139 you are seeing is coming from Javascript.  The AjaxControlToolKit seems to be hardcoded to a height of 139 pixels and on each click of the header sets one or more of .ajax__calendar_days table, .ajax__calendar_months table, .ajax__calendar_years table to  0, 139 or -139.  I am looking into how to override this myself.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this with as little hassle as possible:

1) Open the **Website\Manage NuGet Packages**  menu item.

2) Install **AjaxControlToolkit.StaticResources** under **Browse**

3) Add a ScriptReference to the ScriptManager control

`<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/AjaxControlToolkit/Bundle" />
        </Scripts>
     </asp:ScriptManager>`

4) Add the Styles.Render expression to the  element.

`<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server"> 
   <%:System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/Content/AjaxControlToolkit/Styles/Bundle") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
     <link href="../../include/css/ajax-calendar-fix.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

5) In Solution Explorer for your project, locate the Scripts\AjaxControlToolkit\Release Folder in your Project Root.

6) Open the Calendar.js file and search for `this._width=`.

7) Change the height and width to the values you have set for the .ajax__container height and width. (They will be right next to each other.)

Notes:

A) In my case we are using git so I also added the Calendar.js file to source control.

B) I also had some conflicting styles on other page controls so I had to make some of the selectors more specific to get borders and backgrounds to appear correctly.

`.ajax__calendar .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_today`  became 
`.ajax__calendar_custom td.ajax__calendar_hover div.ajax__calendar_today` for example.